# Java, regular expression catching string with white-space

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my original String named 'response':

```
String response = "attributes[{"displayName":"Joe Smith","fact":"super"},{"displayName":"Kieron Kindle","fact":"this is great"}]";
```

I'm trying to parse the String and extract all the id values e.g

```
String[0] = Joe Smith
String[1] = Kieron Kindle

Pattern idPattern = Pattern.compile("\"displayName\":(\\w)"); // regular expression
Matcher matcher = idPattern.matcher(response);

while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

When i try to print the value nothing is printed to screen (no exception)
the regex expression looks for `"displayName":"` as a left bracket and `"` as right bracket then extracts any words `(\\w)` between them?
Appreciate any help!
Removed the `\n` characters from my regex, that was a formating mistake, sorry guys!

Comment: You should use a JSON parser.

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It, Updated question to remove `\n`

Comment: @bobbyrne01 `(\\w)` matches a single word i.e an `alphabet` or a `digit` or `_`..Your regex fails since `\\w` would not match `"`..Also you should use quatifiers like `+`,`*` that matches 0 or 1 to many times

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It, i went for Rohit Jain's answer, cheers for input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But why have you used a `\n` in your regex? That should be `\"`. Also you have used `\\w` which matches just a single character. You need to use a quantifier with that. And a `Reluctant one`.

So, your modified regex is like this: -

```
Pattern.compile("\"displayName\":\"(\\w+?)\""); // This won't consider space
```

But, since your `String` can also contain space, so you should not use `\\w`. It will not match a space.

So, finally, you should use this regex, which matches any character in between two inverted commas, except `inverted comma` itself: -

```
Pattern.compile("\"displayName\":\"([^\"]+)\"");
```

With the above pattern substituted in your code, your output would be like this: -

```
"Joe Smith"
"Kieron Kindle"
```

---

You can read more about Regex in these tutorials: -

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! What check does this part do? `[^\"]`

Comment: `[]` is a character class.. `^` inside it is for negation.. `\"` is for inverted comma `(")`.. So, that pattern means `any character except "`. Of course strings between two `inverted commas` does not contain an inverted comma right. So, this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this `regex`

```
\"displayName\":\"(.*?)\"
```

`(.*?)` matches 0 to many characters

**OR**[correcting your regex]

```
\"displayName\":\"([\w\s]+)\"
```

`([\w\s]+)` matches a word i.e `\w` **or** a space i.e `\s` 1 to many times i.e `+`

`Group1` now has the data