# Java's Scanner. How to match whitespace?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose, I need to match parentheses containing whitespace.

Here is a snippet:

```
String input = "( ) ( ) ( )";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s\\)");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
scanner.useDelimiter("\\n");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

System.out.println(scanner.hasNext(pattern)); // false
System.out.println(matcher.find()); // true
System.out.println(matcher.start(0) + " " + matcher.end(0)); // 0 3
```

Matcher does exactly what I need, but Scanner doesn't.

The question was not asked correctly. My purpose was to grab sequentially all ( ) tokens in string with scanner, because matcher seems to have inconvenient API for such task.
I should have read documentation thoroughly.

The method what I need is:

```
scanner.findInLine(pattern);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java, regular expression catching string with white-space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313493/java-regular-expression-catching-string-with-white-space)

Comment: Minor note: if you want to use new line as delimiter don't use \\n but \n or even better result of `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: The body doesn't seem to clearly support the title. What is the question exactly?

Comment: @czarpino, for some reason I was sure, that this behavior is related to whitespace. That's why it has such title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the javadoc from Scanner.hasNext(Pattern):

> Returns true if the next **complete token** matches the specified pattern...

So, since your pattern doesn't match the whole token `"( ) ( ) ( )"` it will return false.

The `Scanner` however has a function called `findInLine` that can do what you want:

```
scanner.findInLine(pattern); // returns "( )" or null if not found
```

(however, this method can skip characters...)

Comment: "however, this method can skip characters" - what do you mean?

Comment: If you have a line `"hello ( ) world ( ) ( )"` the first call with will find the first `"( )"` effectively skipping `"hello"` the second call will find the second (skipping `"world"`) and the third call will find the third. The forth call will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `"\\n"` as delimiter (and hence override the default value which is a whitespace) the whole input `"( ) ( ) ( )"` becomes a token.

As the `hasNext` tries to match the **complete** token with the `pattern` it returns `false`.

From the documentation the method [**`Scanner.hasNext(Pattern pattern)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)

> Returns true if the next complete token matches the specified pattern.

So in your case the method call is actually trying to match `"( ) ( ) ( )"` with a `"( )"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String input = "( ) ( ) ( )";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s\\)");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        scanner.useDelimiter(pattern);  //**CHANGED**
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        System.out.println(scanner.hasNext()); //**CHANGED**
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
        System.out.println(matcher.start(0) + " " + matcher.end(0)); // 0 3
```

Update your code as above.

You misunderstood `useDelimiter()`. You have to set `Pattern` as delimiter to your `Scanner` object.

Comment: I need to grab ( ) not to split by it. In your case scanner.next() doesn't return ( ).