# Is there a regex expression suitable for splitting two one digit numbers separated by a whitespace?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm prompting the user for input using the java scanner. The input needs to be two single digits from 0-2 separated  by a whitespace (eg. "1 2").

When I try do \s to split "1 2" i get an arrayoutofbounds exception

whereas when i split "1-2" with \- it works perfectly fine.

I'm completely new to regex and would really appreciate some help :)
My code:

```
    public void x() {
    int n = -1;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Pick your coordinates. X goes first. Eg. 1 1");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        // input = input.replaceAll("\\s", "-").toLowerCase();
        parts = input.split("\\d{1}\\s\\d{1}");
        String x = parts[0];
        String y = parts[1];
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.valueOf(i));
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
        if (matchFound) {
            break;
        } else {
            n = i;
            System.out.println("match N");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("t");
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the for-loop? The problem is that your compiling i (a number from 0 to 2) input a pattern, then you're checking this against x. I'm pretty sure that x isn't what you think it is (print out i, x, and y). Therefore the output isn't even close to what you want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, if you keep your mouse on the `split` you can see the documentation of the method:

> public String[] split(String regex)
>
> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
> the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
> strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
>
> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results
> with these expressions:
>
> ```
>     +-------+-------------------------+
>     | Regex |          Result         |
>     +-------+-------------------------+
>     | :     | { "boo", "and", "foo" } |
>     | o     | { "b", "", ":and:f" }   |
>     +-------+-------------------------+
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> regex - the delimiting regular expression
>
> Returns:
>
> the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches
> of the given regular expression

Therefore, you only have to pass in `\\s` to split by any space character.

Try

```
parts = input.split("\\s");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
\d{1}\s\d{1}
```

`\d{1}` = Match any digit, 1 time
`\s` = Followed by Any whitespace

Comment: I got an array out of bounds exception when i tried that- here is my code
https://hasteb.in/atumafen.gradle

Comment: @orang3juic3, Update your question and post your code with the question.

Comment: I see, there are some unique caveats of this java scanner. Perhaps this can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251157/javas-scanner-how-to-match-whitespace

also, are you not able to use a simple space? like \d{1} \d{1}

Comment: how would i implement this? sorry i'm pretty new to java  and im pretty tired. thanks for all your help so far

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

> split(String regex)
>
> Splits this string **around matches** of the given regular expression.

So, you are trying to split string in the wrong way.

If you want to validate that pattern then you can do this by the following approach:

```
input.matches("\\d{1}\\s\\d{1}")
```